# Why can't I add other character in my code about grading students?

Tags: c

In the following code *a,b,c,d,e* are "subjects" (as in class) and the variable *perc* is the average of the marks for the "subjects".

I can't figure out what is wrong in the code, I can't write anything after pressing enter while writing mark of first subject.

```
//Calculating the grade of students

#include<stdio.h>

main()
{

int a,b,c,d,e  ;
printf("Enter the marks of the following subjects \n") ;
scanf("%d ,%d ,%d ,%d ,%d"), &a,&b,&c,&d,&e ;

float perc ;
perc= (a+b+c+d+e)/5 ;

printf("Your percentage is %f \n", perc);

if (perc>90)
printf("You have A grade") ;
else if (perc>70)
printf("You have B grade") ;
else if (perc>50)
printf("You have C grade") ;
else if (perc>35)
printf("You have D grade") ;
else if (perc<35)
printf("Failed") ;

}
```

Would appreciate some help

Comment: Note that the value of `perc` will always be an integer because the calculation only involves integer variables and an integer divisor.  That will be converted to a `float` on assignment.  Use `/ 5.0F` to do a floating point calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the usage of *scanf()* in reading multiple *int's*
in order to do so you need to get read of the **","** in the *scanf()*

Thus replacing:

```
scanf("%d ,%d ,%d ,%d ,%d"), &a,&b,&c,&d,&e;
```

In:

```
scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &a,&b,&c,&d,&e);
```

and also divide by 5.0 instead of 5:

```
perc= (a+b+c+d+e)/5.0 ;
```

Now it will work as expected.

P.S. you also had problem with the placing of ")"

Comment: Note that the numbers entered must be separated with commas — and the code should check how many values were read before using them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I just pointed out the problem in his code. I agree that usually it is preferred to check and guard the inputing process to avoid problems

Comment: When providing answers to beginners, it is a good idea to point out the other problem in the code — that the input is not checked.  Unchecked inputs are errors/bugs.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Will take this into consideration in future answers of mine. I agree that there is few points that should have been explained further.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has few errors,

`scanf("%d ,%d ,%d ,%d ,%d"), &a,&b,&c,&d,&e;`

It should be `scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e);`

And `perc = (a+b+c+d+e)/5;` should be `perc = (a+b+c+d+e)/5.0;`

Comment: This won't fix the issue

Comment: but 5=5.0 then why do we have to put 5.0?

Answer (score 0):

This is a syntax problem. Replace your scanf line with the following:

```c
scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e);
```

Answer (score 0):

You use non-whitespace characters `,` in the format string. According to [the function description](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), each such character in the format string consumes exactly one identical character from the input stream, or causes the function to fail if the next character on the stream does not compare equal. Thus, your input format shall strictly follow the following pattern `any-number, any-number, any-number, any-number, any-number` and only after it printed you shall press the enter key. In other cases your program fails